# How to launch programmers notepad from command prompt

Tags: java, windows, cmd, text-editor

ok in cmd prompt when i give a this command      `notepad xyz`
it launches the notepad application . but instead of notepad i want it to launch programmer note pad since im going to use this mainly for practicing /learning java.

I set the path variable for the programmers notepad directory that didn't help at all.

Comment: The command is the path to the EXE file for Programmer's Notepad.

Comment: To clarify, did you add the correct EXE to the PATH variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reopening the terminal after updating the path env variable? Also first try to see if it works by typing the full path yourself. For example: I have a `file.xml` inside `c:\`. I typed `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Programmer's Notepad\pn.exe" file.xml` in the terminal and it works as expected.

I then added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Programmer's Notepad\` to the `path` env variable that is included in the System Variables section. Closed the already opened terminal, reopened and then typed `pn file.xml` (with c:\ being my current directory) and it works again as expected.

Comment: thank you looks like i didnt add a "\" the end . Is the path variable case sensitive ?

Comment: quick test: open a terminal type `echo %path%` and then type `echo %PATH%`. You will see no complaints and the result is the same. Also check:http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them under *Unix derivatives (FreeBSD, GNU / Linux, OS X)* it says `Keep in mind that variable names are case sensitive`

Answer (score 0):

First, check properly whether you have added the PATH variable correctly!

And then Run : pn.exe in command prompt (cmd.exe), not notepad....